# RxJava operator to segment stream of random-sized lists into uniform sized lists without losing items

Tags: rx-java2

I have a stream of list of items (i.e. each emission is a list). The lists are of varying length. I want an operator (or several in combination) that can re-segment the lists so that each list is the same length.

Here is a simple example with arrays.

```
int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] array2 = {4, 5};
int[] array3 = {6, 7, 8, 9};

Observable.just(array1, array2, array3)
        .emitGroupsOf2() // <--- what operator can I use here?
        .subscribe(ints -> {
            // I want:
            // emit {1,2}
            // emit {3,4}
            // emit {5,6}
            // emit {7,8}
            // complete
        });
    }
```

In this example, I want to "hold on to 3" until I hear 4; then I want to "hold on to 5" until I hear 6. Finally I want to "throw away" 9 since we never got another value to create another pair.

I've looked at `map` and `scan` and `buffer` but none of those work quite right.

Answer (score 1):

RxJava does not support primitive arrays so you have to do some wrapping and unwrapping:

```java
Observable.just(array1, array2, array3)
    .concatMap(array -> Observable.range(0, array.length).map(idx -> array[idx]))
    .buffer(2)
    .map(buf -> {
        int[] result = new int[buf.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = buf.get(i);
        }
        return result;
    })
    .subscribe(ints -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints)));
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't support primitive arrays, do you mean it's auto-boxing under the hood?

Comment: It means you have to box in the primitive types yourself.

Comment: Really? Hmmm. But the code in my initial post works just fine. I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: How could it work if it is in java and there is no emitGroupsOf2 operatorn in RxJava? You want to rebatch primitive arrays for which you have to unroll each and you can't do the unrolling directly with a RxJava standard operator. fromArray requires object array.

Comment: I mean the dealing with primitive arrays =) I just put `emitGroupsOf2` in there as an example of what I'm looking for =). Ok so you're saying rxjava doesn't support unrolling (as in your example) primitives. I thought you meant I can't use primitive arrays at all.